# Constructing Net problem

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

so I'm trying build a simple net that will help me find the winner in a competition. I would like to use as input "Name", "FA" and "Force", and obtain "Winner" or "Loser" as output. First I created the net encoders for "Name" (using Tokens) and "Winner"/"Loser"(using class).

[image: Dataset Used]

```
nameenc = 
 NetEncoder[{"Tokens", {"Blackbeard", "Bonnie", "Buck", "Crossblades",
     "Fairfax", "Federismo", "Franchisco", "Gooblah", "Lucky", "Ned", 
    "Stripey", "Orvinn", "Peg Leg", "Puffo", "Dan", "Edmund", 
    "Squire", "Stuff", "Tailhook", "Sproggie"}}]
winnerenc = NetEncoder[{"Class", {"Winner", "Loser"}}]
```

Then I created a net that will take the information of each competitor and give a partial output. net1 for pirate1, net2 for pirate2 and so on

```
net1 = NetGraph[{CatenateLayer[], 
   LinearLayer[]}, {{NetPort["Name"], NetPort["FA"], 
     NetPort["Force"]} -> 1 -> 2 -> NetPort["Pirate1"]}]
```

Then I would like to create a net that will use those four nets as input and give as output the name associated with the class "Winner"/"Loser". Can someone help me with this part?

Obs: If this problem would be easier or better to solved by using Classifier or Predict I would accept as solution, I didn't know how to build the training set in a way that would use the four competitors informations as input and "Name", "Winner"/"Loser" as output.

Answer (score 1):

> Obs: If this problem would be easier or better to solved by using Classifier or Predict I would accept as solution

I would recommend using `Classify` for this use-case. If you find yourself needing more customization over the Method/layers you can switch to NeuralNets.

Here's an example to get you started. I'll make a dummy dataset using random names and feature values. The "Winner" or "Loser" classes get assigned with a weighted probability based on the first letter of the name: If it starts with a letter before 'K' it has a 75% chance of being a "Winner", otherwise it's a "Loser" (Note: the contrived example was such that the best guess was not 50/50 and we could evaluate if the classifier learned anything)

```
names = EntityValue[RandomEntity["GivenName", 10], "Name"]
dummyDataGenerator[] := 
 With[{features = {RandomChoice[names], RandomInteger[{-2, -1}], 
     RandomReal[]}},
  features -> 
   RandomChoice[
    If[First[ToCharacterCode[StringTake[features[[1]], 1]]] < 
       75(*FromCharacterCode[75]\[Equal]"K"*),
         {0.25, 0.75}, {0.75, 0.25}] -> {"Loser","Winner"}]]
dummyData = Table[dummyDataGenerator[], {100000}];
{training, testing} = TakeDrop[dummyData, 75000];

Out[]= {"Eph", "Shahira", "Isahbella", "Delima", "Pancho", \
"Shreeda", "Cable", "Johnnita", "Teana", "Hermolaos"}
```

We can then train and test the classifier:

```
c = Classify[training(*,Method\[Rule]{"NeuralNetwork","NetworkDepth"\[Rule]2}*)];
ClassifierMeasurements[c, testing, "Accuracy"]

Out[]=0.75056
```

If you indeed want to use a Neural Network, you can check the "NeuralNetwork" `Method` for `Classify` for starters (commented out in snippet above).

Comment: In this case they compete as four, so between "Eph", "Shahira", "Isahbella", "Delima" and their associated data I wanna know who is the winner. I tried organizing the data in the format {{"Eph",n1,n2} -> Winner,{"Shahira",n1,n2} -> Loser,{" "Isahbella",n1,n2} -> Loser,{ "Delima",n1,n2} -> Loser}, but because is not in the format {input}-> {Output} didn't work. 
Then I tried organizing the data as {{"Eph",n1,n2},{"Shahira",n1,n2} ,{""Isahbella",n1,n2},{ "Delima",n1,n2}} -> "Eph", but I didn't get a good accuracy(I think is because the number of classes).